# Why is my RecyclerView showing Incorrect order of CardView items?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView of CardViews of Food (class) objects. A weird thing that is happening is that when I'm using a method to add a new Food object to the ArrayList that I'm using, and notifying the adapter that a value has been added, the Card gets added on screen, but it has a different set of values.

I'm using 2 placeholder Food objects to show on screen at default, and pressing the Add button is supposed to add a new object with name "Name", but instead I get another copy of the first placeholder.

When too many Cards are added to screen, swiping up and down changes the order of the cards, and suddenly, the new items (with the correct data) appear!

What's wrong?
The app doesn't crash btw.

***Function to add new Food object to ArrayList called 'foods':***

```
public void addFood(){
   foods.add(new Food("Name",0,3,2)); //a constructor
foodAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Comment: Use notifyDatasetchanged instead of itemchange.

Comment: Is it your intention to insert the item at the first position in your list (index 0 .i.e notifyItemInserted(0)) ? To better help you, provide the code related to the adapter set up and the foods class.

Comment: Yes, it is my intention that every single time I add something, it should go to the top of the page (like a stack). Should I use notifyDataSetChanged too (besides notifyItemInserted?)

Comment: @Arc Did I miss something in the documentation about the Recycler view?

Comment: @SohailSaha, you figured it out, it was related to the position. 

Comment: @Arc Yup, it sort of just clicked 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was that calling .add(Object) on the ArrayList item 'foods' actually appended the new Object to the end of the list, meanwhile, Adapter.notifyItemInserted(0) made the Recycler view think that Position 0 got the new Card, whereas it was actually Position last.
This made the wrong item show up at the RecyclerView.

So, as obvious, ***the fix is to use the ArrayList.add(position,object) constructor instead of .add(object), where position shows where the new element was inserted.***

***So, the correct code is:***

```
public void addFood(){
   foods.add(0, new Food("Name", 0, 3, 2)); //a constructor
   foodAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

If you want the new object to be inserted at a different position, simply pass that position in place of the 0 above.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change `foodAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)` into `foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or `foodAdapter.notifyItemInserted(foods.size() - 1)`.